# Change Background color of RMarkdown PDF Code Chunk

Tags: r, pdf, r-markdown

I am trying to change the code chunk formatting options in a rmarkdown document that is generated as a pdf.  I want the formatting for these code chunks to be different. I want similar to

```
class.source="bg-info", class.output="bg-warning"
```

for HTML documents.

Answer (score -1):

Not sure if I understood your question correctly. Please always include an minimum working example (MWE) with your question for greater clarity. Since it is not outline exactly what is required, a general outline is provided.

To change the code chunk formatting options in a Rmarkdown document (PDF or HTML) you can use the built-in [Pandoc Syntax Highlighting](https://www.garrickadenbuie.com/blog/pandoc-syntax-highlighting-examples/) styles. You can change both the background of code chunks, and the font color. All you have to do is to add the `highlight` in YAML.

`highlight` specifies the syntax highlighting style. Some alternatives are `default`, `tango`, `pygments`, `kate`, `monochrome`, `espresso`, `zenburn`, `haddock`, `breezedark`, and `textmate`. You can also use `null` to prevent any highlighting. For example:

```
title: "A nice document"
output:
  html_document:
    highlight: haddock
```

You can change the the appearance of your code and output with some predefined CSS classes for backgrounds in HTML: `"bg-primary"`, `"bg-success"`, `"bg-info"`, `"bg-warning"`, and `"bg-danger"`. Arbitrary class names and user-define custom CSS rules are also allowed. A detailed discussion can be found in Yihui Xie's [R Markdown Cookbook](https://bookdown.org/yihui/rmarkdown-cookbook/chunk-styling.html).